# create new lines based on words from string

Tags: python

I have a txt file with several lines like:

```
CLOSED ES UN CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD)) IF RELY CLOSED ASER (SSDA, IWWD)
```

I'm trying split into new lines based on some words ( i.e CLOSED and IF )
create new line and split the string result should be like

```
CLOSED ES UN \
CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD))  
IF RELY \
CLOSED ASER ( SSDA,IWWD )
```

I've tried

```
x = open('file.txt')\
for word in x.read().split('CLOSED|,NOT'):\
    print (word)
```

Thanks for you guidance

Comment: Are the backslashes really part of the output and the code?

Comment: `str.split()` doesn't use regular expressions. Use `re.split()` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
CLOSED ES UN CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD)) IF RELY CLOSED ASER (SSDA, IWWD)
CLOSED ES UN CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD)) IF RELY CLOSED ASER (SSDA, IWWD)
```

You could do something like:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = re.sub('[^^](CLOSED|IF)', '\n\\1', f.read())

print(text)
```

Output:

```
CLOSED ES UN
CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD))
IF RELY
CLOSED ASER (SSDA, IWWD)
CLOSED ES UN
CLOSED DE LO QUE ((DSSS, 121244, ADASD))
IF RELY
CLOSED ASER (SSDA, IWWD)
```